# Nginx proxy_pass не переправляет на бекенд

Tags: vue.js, nginx

У меня бекэнд расположен на 5500 порту локального компьютера, при переходе на /api идет в корень сайта и иногда выдает ошибку 502. Как можно это решить?
Вот конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/chat/dist;
    index index.html;
    charset utf-8;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5500/;
        proxy_set_header    Host    localhost;
    }
    location / {
        root /var/www/chat/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5500/api;`

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну теперь уже 404 ошибка)

Comment: `location /api` замените на `location /`, и установите как подсказал @AlexeyTen

Comment: @dmtr, А это разве никак не повлияет на следующий location /?

Comment: @СергейЕлпашев повлияет, не заметил. знать бы структуру вашу, что и куда, легче было бы подсказать.

Comment: @dmtr мне нужно чтобы на /api располагался бекенд Golang сервер, который запущен на том же компьютере на 5500 порте. Фронтенд бы отправлял ему запросы. А через 127.0.0.1:5500 даже при запуске сервера локально не работало.

Comment: А бэкенд ваш реально располагается по пути `/api` ? Что у вас тут - `/var/www/chat/dist` ?  @СергейЕлпашев

Comment: @dmtr, бекенд располагается по адресу 127.0.0.1:5500, в папке /var!/chat/dist лежит собранный проект vue

Comment: Ошибочка, в /var/www/chat/dist

Comment: В вашем конфиге запросы вида `http://example.com/api?query=smth` перенаправляются на `http://127.0.0.1:5500/?query=smth`. Как сконфигурирован ваш бэкэнд? Он поддерживает такие запросы? Если нет, то ничего удивительного в ошибкак 404 и 5xx

Comment: Если ваш бэкэнд обрабатывает REST запросы, то у вас будет двойной слэш, так как Вы указали nginx, что /api надо заменять на /. Например, rest-запросы `/api/object/verb` станут `//object/verb/`. Ваш бэкэнд такое понимает?

Comment: @PakUula мой фронтенд делает POST запросы на localhost/api/messages, мне надо чтобы бекенд понимал как запрос на 127.0.0.1:5500/messages

Comment: Попробуйте добавить / в конце location: `location /api/`

Answer (score 0):

http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

> Если директива `proxy_pass` указана с URI, то при передаче запроса серверу часть нормализованного URI запроса, соответствующая location, заменяется на URI, указанный в директиве

В вашем случае `/api` заменяется на `/` и из запроса `/api/messages` получается `//messages`. Подозреваю, что vue на этом ломается.

В общем, нужно просто добавить слеш в `location`.

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5500/;
    proxy_set_header    Host    localhost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал `upstream` и заменил `root` на `alias`, исправил в соответствии с вашими предложениями. А так же оказалось, что у меня 5500 порт был занят) Теперь всё работает.
Получилось вот так:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    charset utf-8;
    location / {
        alias /var/www/chat/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
    }
}
```